# How to recode a three level factor

Tags: r, database, factors

My dataset is one which contains information about various children. I have a complicated factor question. I have two variables: Parent 1 finance and Parent 2 finance (which take one of three values: low, medium, high income). I want to make a third variable, "guardian finance" as some of my subjects only have one parent. How can I recode it so that the highest level of finance is selected, and, if the child is from a one parent household, this is carried over to the new, "Guardian" variable.

```
       p1        n
      <int>    <int>
1      low     100
2      medium  306
3      high    96
```

```
        p2            n
       <int>       <int>
1      low         227
2      medium      230
3      high        243
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to get the highest 'n' among the the two datsets, do a join between the two columns by the 'p' columnss and then use `pmax` to return the `max` between the 'n' columns

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("p1" = "p2") %>%
     mutate(n = pmax(n.x, n.y) %>%
     select(p1, n)
```

Comment: I like that answer but how would I do it if I'm working in the same data set?

Comment: @Nick In that case, just do `df1 %>% mutate(newcol = pmax(firstcol, secondcol))` please change with the actual column name

Comment: Output is as follows: 

```
> x %>% count(Guardian)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  test      n
  <lgl> <int>
1 TRUE   9068
2 NA     1511
```

It looks like it did not keep the levels. Why would this be?

Comment: @Nick Please update your post as I am not able to understand the format

Comment: @Nick As I said, it is very difficult to read the format from the comments.  Can you please edit your post

Comment: I just answered it. Sorry, new to Stack overflow.